# Firing a shot from a character in the direction of mouse click

Tags: actionscript-3, math, game-physics

So first off i'd like to state that i am not very good at AS3, i'm completely self taught so i am sure that there are many things i've done badly, inefficiently or plain wrong and i'm happy for any comments on these if there is things i can improve.

So i'm trying to add the functionality for a player to be able to click on a part of my game and a"hook" will fire from the character in the direction of the mouse click for a certain length. the end of this will then be collision detection between that hook and a platform.

however the problem i'm having is i have no idea how to run the code which will locate the angle which the hook needs to be fired in, i understand this is a certain amount of maths and any help which can be given would be helpful ( even if you can't fix the problem for me)

So far i have been able to locate the x and y positions of both my hero and the position on the mouse click this code is shown below:

```
 public function Hookshot (event:MouseEvent):void {

    PlatformInstance[i] =new Platform();
        var _point:Point = localToGlobal (new Point(mouseX,mouseY));
         var heroX:int = Smallclock_hero.x;
         var heroY:int = Smallclock_hero.y;
         trace (heroX)
        trace (heroY)
         trace(_point.x)
        trace(_point.y)
    }
```

I'm not sure there is any other relevant code as of yet as i haven't been able to wrap my head around how to do this kind of maths.

if there is any additional code you need or any questions you have please ask away and thanks in advance!

Comment: Basic trigonometry will help. The triangle you can draw between the points is a right angled triangle. Which means a squared + b squared = c squared which means you can find out the angle to shoot fairly easilt. Hope that helps you. https://www.google.com.au/search?q=basic+trigonometry+examples+right+angled+triangle&oq=basic+trigonometry+examples+right+angled+triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.atan2(y, x)` will convert an x and y value into an angle:

```
var mousePos:Point = localToGlobal(new Point(mouseX,mouseY));
var heroPos:Point = localToGlobal(new Point(Smallclock_hero.x, Smallclock_hero.y));

var dx:Number = mousePos.x - heroPos.x;
var dy:Number = mousePos.y - heroPos.y;
var radians:Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

// Convert the radians value to degrees
var angleInDegrees:Number = radians * 180/Math.PI;

trace(angleInDegrees);
```

Math.atan2() documentation:
[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#atan2()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#atan2%28%29)

Comment: Thanks very much ! that seems to work perfectly! just a quick question, what is the difference between Math.atan2 and Math.atan??

Comment: As Digital Utopia's example, with Math.atan() you supply one argument only: the y/x. Both functions give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't so much AS3 related, as it is simple algebra.

If you have the x,y of the character, and the x,y of the target, then you just need to do the equation of a line to get the angle.

atan((Y2-Y1)/(X2-X1))

That should give you radians, and then simply multiply it by (180/pi) to get degrees

Comment: I know this is going to sound extremely dumb, but is there a way you could give em an example of this? finding myself getting more and more confused.

Comment: Let's say your character is at x=5,y=10, and your target is at x=9,y=20. So you start off by subtracting the two 

(y) 20-10=10
(x) 9-5 = 4

Then divide y by x: 10/4 = 2.5

Then take the atan(2.5) of that, which is 1.19028995 and that's in radians, so you want to turn that into degrees for your angle. and to do that, you multiply it by 180/pi, which will give you something like 68.19 degrees.